# How to write unit tests for SCSS function?

Tags: unit-testing, sass

`func.scss`:

```
@import './variables.scss';

@function r($px, $isFixed: true) {
  @if $px != 0 {
    @return if($isFixed, $px / $ratio + 0.01, $px / $ratio) / $browser-default-font-size * 1rem;
  } @else {
    @return 0;
  }
}
```

How to write unit tests for SCSS function? And it provides assertion, mock, stub functions like `jestjs` or `sinonjs`. So that I can mock the `@import` scss module and its functions, variables(`$browser-default-font-size`) and so on.